# Retry function - I2C hung state handling PIC XC8

Tags: pic, i2c, c, serial, xc8

This may be a very borderline Stack Overflow question, but I decided to post here because I'm dealing with the I2C protocol for a PIC MCU in XC8.

I'm learning how to talk with devices over I2C and it's going quite well, but I'm not sure of the best way to deal with a hung state from a not-acknowledge from a slave. The problem comes from the while() loops and the program not progressing until they're met (or not true - you know what I mean). My first method was with a watch dog reset, but I didn't like re-initializing everything any time something goes wrong.

I've consolidated all the writing of the registers to a function:

```
void I2Cwrite(unsigned char SLAVE, unsigned char REG, unsigned char DATA)
{
    SSPCON2bits.SEN = 1; // RESET
    while(SSPCON2bits.SEN == 1);
    SSPBUF = SLAVE;
    PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;
    while(PIR1bits.SSPIF == 0);
    while(SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT == 1);
    SSPBUF = REG;
    PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;
    while(PIR1bits.SSPIF == 0);
    while(SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT == 1);
    SSPBUF = DATA;
    PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;
    while(PIR1bits.SSPIF == 0);
    while(SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT == 1);
    PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;
    SSPCON2bits.PEN = 1;
    while(PIR1bits.SSPIF == 0);
}
```

Then all I have to do is write my data to a function like this:

```
I2Cwrite(DRVwrite, 0x01, 0x07);
I2Cwrite(DRVwrite, 0x1A, 0b11011110);
I2Cwrite(DRVwrite, 0x16, 0b01010110);
I2Cwrite(DRVwrite, 0x17, 0b01011110);
I2Cwrite(DRVwrite, 0x1E, 0b00110000);
I2Cwrite(DRVwrite, 0x1B, 0b10011100);
```

If I fall into a hung state mid write, what is a good way to jump to the start of that particular I2C write function and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer involves a Timer 2 to keep track of timing, and loops to give the ability of restarting from the beginning. The main send function is now grouped in a while(1) loop to allow multiple retries or parts. Each section of potential hung state is broken into a PART.

Timer 2 is set to a high priority interrupt, when overflows (because it has been waiting for too long) it sets a variable called TIMEOUT to 1. The ISR looks like:

```
void __interrupt(high_priority) High_ISR(void)
{
    if(PIR1bits.TMR2IF == 1)
    {
        TIMEOUT = 1;
        PIR1bits.TMR2IF = 0;
    }
}
```

When the program jumps back after servicing the ISR into waiting in the while loop, the while loops now have a function in them that breaks the wait if TIMEOUT equals 1.

```
void I2Cwrite(unsigned char SLAVE, unsigned char REG, unsigned char DATA)
{
    while(1)
    {
        TMR2 = 0;
        T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1;
        
        if(PART == 0)
        {
            SSPCON2bits.SEN = 1; // RESET
            while(SSPCON2bits.SEN == 1);
            SSPBUF = SLAVE;
            PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;
            while(PIR1bits.SSPIF == 0);
            while(SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT == 1)
            {
                if(TIMEOUT == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 0;
        }
        if(PART == 1)
        {
            SSPBUF = REG;
            PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;
            while(PIR1bits.SSPIF == 0);
            while(SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT == 1)
            {
                if(TIMEOUT == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 0;
        }
        if(PART == 2)
        {
            SSPBUF = DATA;
            PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;
            while(PIR1bits.SSPIF == 0);
            while(SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT == 1)
            {
                if(TIMEOUT == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 0;
        }
        if(PART == 3)
        {
            PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;
            SSPCON2bits.PEN = 1;
            while(PIR1bits.SSPIF == 0)
            {
                if(TIMEOUT == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 0;
        }
        if(TIMEOUT == 1) /////// Try again and start from beginning
        {
            PART = 0;
            TIMEOUT = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(PART == 3) // If the last part has been sent, break the while(1) loop
            {
                PART = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                PART++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I2C writes should never fail with a NAK. Except if it is an intended feature, like an I2C EEPROM being busy during write so it does not respond until ready. So normally a NAK means there is a hardware problem, like chip not present, chip in reset, or not detecting bus transactions properly. Of course it is a nice feature to exit I2C functions if there is an error and report the error in code. But if a chip that is expexted to respond is missing, there is likely other bits communicated unreliably as well, so you can't just assume all other transactions were fine.

Comment: That is a nice solution @ezra_vdj, well done for getting there all by yourself. You can now put a timer-checking code into a macro or an inline function to avoid your code being DRY. In the actual production code, you'd usually make the whole I2C transaction interrupt-driven which would avoid blocking code (you'd still use a timer to detect time-outs though)

Comment: Thanks @AndrejsGasilovs ! One of those figure-it-out as you ask it questions I guess. What do you mean by DRY code?